# MyBatis association without column

Tags: associations, mybatis, spring-mybatis

In a mapper **A** I have got a `resultMap` which contains an association loaded using another mapper's (mapper **B**) method and the method on the mapper **B** has no arguments.

How should the association look like in the mapper **A**?

I've tried the following:

```
<association property="property" column=""
             select="mapperB.findObjectWithNoArguments"
             javaType="Object"/>
```

but that does not work, the loaded value is null (even though it actually exists and should be loaded).

Removing the `column` attribute yields *Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapping is missing column attribute for property property* error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, if you really want to have the mapping done through XML, the only possible approach is to add a fake a column with a truth-y value, e.g. one:

```
SELECT
  1 AS column_to_force_association
FROM ...
```

and then use this faked column in the association:

```
<association property="property" column="column_to_force_association"
             select="mapperB.findObjectWithNoArguments"
             javaType="Object"/>
```

But this looks nowhere to optimal, so the better approach is to probably load the entity without the value and set it in a service using a setter.